# MongoDB Aggregation - Select only same value from array inside lookup

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have aggregation like this:

```
Produk.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "kis_m_kategoriproduks",
        localField: "idSubKategori",
        foreignField: "subKategori._id",
        as: "kategori",
      },
    },
    { $unwind: "$kategori" },
    { $sort: { produk: 1 } },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 0,
        id: "$id",
        dataKategori: {
          idKategori: "$kategori._id",
          kategori: "$kategori.kategori",
          idSubKategori: "$idSubKategori",
          subKategori: "$kategori.subKategori",
        },
      },
    },
  ])
```

current result is :

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": [
        {
            "dataKategori": {
                "idKategori": "6195bbec8ee419e6a9b8329d",
                "kategori": "Kuliner",
                "idSubKategori": "6195bc0f8ee419e6a9b832a2",
                "subKategori": [
                    {
                        "nama": "Food",
                        "_id": "6195bc0f8ee419e6a9b832a2"
                    },
                    {
                        "nama": "Drink",
                        "_id": "6195bc258ee419e6a9b832a8"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I only want to display data in `subKategori` that the `_id` match with `idSubKategori`. this what I expected:

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": [
        {
            "dataKategori": {
                "idKategori": "6195bbec8ee419e6a9b8329d",
                "kategori": "Kuliner",
                "idSubKategori": "6195bc0f8ee419e6a9b832a2",
                "subKategori": [
                    {
                        "nama": "Food",
                        "_id": "6195bc0f8ee419e6a9b832a2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

here is my `$kategori` schema:

```
const schema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
      kategori: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
      },
      subKategori: [
        {
          id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
          nama: String,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      timestamps: false,
    }
  );
```

any suggestion?

Comment: Use $lookup with nested pipeline syntax to add extra filters there https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-subqueries-on-a-joined-collection

Comment: hi @AlexBlex, thanks for your replies but can you provides some examples for me? I was new at MongoDB and I cant fully understand about documentation

Answer (score 0):

I fix the problem by add `$filter` inside `$project` like this:

```
  dataKategori: {
    idKategori: "$kategori._id",
    kategori: "$kategori.kategori",
    subKategori: {
      $arrayElemAt: [
        {
          $filter: {
            input: "$kategori.subKategori",
            as: "sub",
            cond: { $eq: ["$$sub._id", "$idSubKategori"] },
          },
        },
        0,
      ],
    },
  },
```

reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42490320/6412375